# Bootstrapping in discontinuous mode

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I am designing a buck converter that would charge a battery and planning to use an N type MOSFET on high side and FAN7085_GF085 driver to go with it.

Datasheet:

(Can't post more than 2 links, sorry).

Application note:

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-9052.pdf

If the converter happens to go to discontinuous mode however, the diode stops conducting -> voltage at transistor source becomes something >0, and the internal recharge path of FAN7085 activates (as much as I understand it according to the application note, page 2).
Doesn't this short out the battery through an inductor and driver circuit?
What if I put a diode in series with an inductor (like I did in this picture)?

[image]

Comment: Which diode stops conducting? What discontinuous mode? PWM frequency? MIN, MAX Duty ratio?

Comment: Note that bootstrapping technique needs switching events to provide power. If the turn off time is too large or too small the bootstrapping does not work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter#Discontinuous_mode

The current stops flowing while transistor is off.


PWM frequency is 62.5kHz; min 1%, max 99% duty cyle.
if that helps.

Comment: Also note that 5V is something too small for gate voltage, ussually  12 to 15V is used.

Comment: Practically you have the worst scenario min 1%, max 99%, low supply voltage.

Comment: But in theory it would still manage to switch according to both formulas i used:

https://www.silabs.com/tools/Pages/bootstrap-calculator.aspx

and

http://www.irf.com/technical-info/designtp/dt98-2.pdf

But ignore that for a second, i am just asking if the driver would short the battery in discontinuous mode.

Comment: A term "short the battery" would mean to short positive and negative pole of the battery, for me. What is your explanation of "short the battery"?

Comment: "Shorting the battery" I admit isn't the best term.
What I am thinking about is this, direct quote from application note:
"In the event that both of the switch (S1 and S2) are turned off, the internal recharge switch of the FAN7085 will provide the path to charge the bootstrap capacitor." That means the current will flow through an inductor in the opposite direction and then to VS pin of FAN7085 and essentialy destroy it.

Comment: During discontinuous mode, the current through L4 would try to reverse (flow from right to left). For this schematic, the current would flow to ground through the bootstrap charge path of FAN7085. It would not be a "short" because of the current limit, but it is probably undesirable. The extra diode D? should prevent that at the expense of extra diode voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a galvanically isolated control, then why not to use opto coupled gate driver instead of making separate opto coupler + gate driver.[image]

In this example you have a device that does the job for you. The gate power supply Vcc can be a galvanically separated DC/DC converter from your's 5V to 15V.

This is how it looks like (https://www.eeweb.com/blog/avago_technologies/isolated-igbt-mosfet-gate-driver-evaluation-board):
[image]

You can see, that unpopulated holes are the place for standard DC/DC converter.

Having a constant gate power supply you can make a duty cylcle from 0% to 100% without problems, which is an unresolvable task for bootstrapping technique, IMO.